# Google cloud shell not opening on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am clicking on activate cloud shell and this is the problem I am facing this: **Cloud Shell is experiencing some issues provisioning a VM to you. Please try again in a few minutes.**

I tried with multiple devices and multiple chrome users. Also tried it in different network with different laptop. Still no difference.

### When I click on activate cloud shell:

[image: When I click on activate cloud shell]

### When I click on activate cloud shell

[image: This is the problem which shows up in 2-3 seconds]

Comment: Despite the fact that documentation [links](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange) here, ServerFault is **not Google** support.  The ServerFault community can only help with [on-topic questions](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and can't resolve billing issues, [outages](https://status.cloud.google.com/)  and similar problems. You get what you pay for and when you don't have [a paid support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support) you're mostly on your own. When you do have a paid support plan, please ask questions there: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases

Comment: Thank you, I found out I can create issues for google cloud with basic plan on this site:  https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers